# How can underfitting and overfitting Classifiers of the same Type perform equally worse?

Tags: machine-learning, validation, overfitting

An rbf support vector classifier is instantiated with different values for C and gamma. Then learning curves are plotted for each of the classifiers. Some classifiers consistently achieve very high training scores, others consistently achieve very low training scores, but all classifiers achieve poor and nearly identical validation scores. How should this result be interpreted?

Comment: Sounds like the train set is not representative of the test set.

Comment: What to do in such a case? My guess is that both an enlargement of the dataset and methods to reduce the number of features (top-k filtering, PCA etc.) would help. However, I have a hard time finding reasons why. Any ideas?